# why is return variable not showing proper type upon hover when using type definition file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using type definition file to declare my types and I'm not able to get the variable which holds the returned value of my typed function to show proper type on hover. Mind you I'm new to typsecript.

.d.ts file has:

```
interface MatchesFound {
  allResults: string[],
}    
export function findMatches(searchTerm: string, options: FindMatchOptions): Promise<MatchesFound>
```

On the js file where I use the function, when I hover over the function itself i see types properly as defined. But when I hover over the returned value I don't see MatchesFound or Promise, I instead see any.

**Edit:**

this is how I envoke the function

```
let matches;
try {
  matches = findMatches('foo', {...options});
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Show how you invoke the function and how you declare a variable that holds the returned value.

Comment: edited op with invoking code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let matches;` implicitly assigns type `any` to `matches`.

You can either declare it with the right type:

`let matches: Promise<MatchesFound>`

or join declaration and initialization:

`let matches = findMatches('foo', {...options}); // Type Promise<MatchesFound>`

Answer (score 0):

Mike S. answer did help figure out the cause of the issue but the solutions suggested didn't work since I'm not using typescript in my javascript, it was just a definition file to avoid a build process.

My variable declaration was needed to be outside a try block. in order to work around that I used jsDoc to specific the type of the variable and that worked nicely along side typescript:

```
/** @type {import('../bin/findMatch').MatchesFound} */
let matchesFound;
```